# How to wrap command-line programs using C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I want to write a C++ "command-line program wrapper" that would launch a Windows command-line program as a subprocess (like a subprocess in Python) and would be able to pass input into the subprocess' stdin and read its stdout. Ideally there would be something like a "sendToSubprocessStdin(string input)" function and a "readFromSubprocessStdout()" function. Are there any libraries that can help me do this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Boost added a very nice [subprocess library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/process.html) in its latest release (1.64).

Comment: I am not aware of any dedicated tool.